# Is it possible to skip grailsVersion validation for a plugin without having to checkout a local copy

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I would like to use a grails plugin that is restricted to grails 2.0 > * > 2.3 while my current grails version is 2.3.3.

Is there a way to avoid having to checkout the plugin source code and changing it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious - which plugin?

Comment: [Kickstart with Bootstrap](http://grails.org/plugin/kickstart-with-bootstrap) , a great plugin I was using with 2.2.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Grails plugins only specify the lower version, having said that, if the author has created the plugin for `2.0 > * > 2.3` either there is a compatibility problem, which forcing it to work does not help, or mistakenly has put the upper version, which you can raise an issue for it.

One alternative is to download the plugin, customize it and use it as `In-Line` plugin. Doc [Specifying Plugin Locations](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#12.1%20Creating%20and%20Installing%20Plug-ins).

```
grails.plugin.location.'grails-ui' = "../grails-grails-ui"
```

Comment: The inline trick will probably be my workaround and an [issue](https://github.com/joergrech/KickstartWithBootstrap/pull/58) about the upper version limitation has been raised already. I am pretty sure the idea was to limit to 2.3.X and not only 2.3.0